# Can someone on maternity leave in the UK earn money by taking freelance work?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

Let's say I work as a social worker (taxes through PAYE) and am on (statutory) maternity leave.

Let's say a local contact centre are looking for people to work there, on a freelance basis.

Am I allowed to work for them and continue to get statutory pay through my permanent social work contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends when you work and how you are employed:

> 3.12 Working in your Maternity Pay Period
>
> If you are getting SMP from one employer and, before your baby is born, you do some work for another employer, your SMP is not affected.
>
> Your SMP will stop if after the baby is born, but before the end of the Maternity Pay Period, you work for an employer who did not employ you in the qualifying week. It is your responsibility to tell the employer paying you SMP about your new job. You must do this as soon as possible, and make sure you return any SMP payment you get that covers the week you started work and any part of the period after you resumed work.
>
> If you do any work in a self-employed capacity during your MPP, then such work will not affect your SMP.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/maternity-benefits-technical-guidance/maternity-benefits-technical-guidance

Basically, as per my interpretation of the above: work for another employer prior to the baby being born - not an issue.  Work for another employer after the baby is born that didn't employ you during your qualifying week - issue.  Work self employed - not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the government website: "Tell your employer you **want to stop work** to have a baby and the day you want your SMP to start. You must give them at least 28 days’ notice (in writing if they ask for it) and proof that you’re pregnant."

It seems quite clear that you get maternity leave payments so you can **stop to work**. If you don't stop to work, you have no right to payments. If you stop to work for your company but then start working for someone else, then you don't stop to work and have no rights to payment.

You don't get paid money as a reward for having a child. You get paid money so you can afford to stop working and look after your child instead. If you don't stop working, there is no reason to give you money.

Comment: While it seems probable this is the right answer, it looks like you are just explaining your opinion. Since we're on law.SE here, would you consider citing the relevant regulations?

Comment: https://www.workingfamilies.org.uk/articles/myth-of-the-month-working-during-maternity-leave/ suggests that it's not a simple "no".